# Is it possible to revert back to Jellybean Stock while keeping ClockworkMod?

Tags: cyanogenmod, 4.2-jelly-bean, clockworkmod-recovery

I am running CM10.1 on my i9300 and use ClockworkMod. Is there a way for me to revert back to JellyBean?

Comment: If you revert back to JB, the recovery image will be overwritten with the stock recovery.

Answer (score 0):

Just flash the firmware you like with [Odin](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2189539).

**Attention:** you will probably lose your data because of the wiping.